# W3 Total Cache not minifying JS and CSS in Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, minify, w3-total-cache

I have my website enabled with w3 total cache plugin and all the minify options have been enabled. Still when i run my site on Google page speed it says that i need to minify js and css. can anybody help me out with this ?

my website: www.inspiria.net.in

Comment: Some of your JS/CSS looks minified to me: http://inspiria.net.in/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/5e3aa/default.include.ff26db.css & http://inspiria.net.in/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/5e3aa/default.include.83c85e.js. How are you including the scripts and CSS that aren't minified?

Comment: Yes but not all get minified. For Example, this one http://inspiria.net.in/wp-content/themes/Avada/js/main.js?ver=3.7 Google page speed is still telling me to minify js and css. But w3 total cache users have experianced that their js and css are minifed via this plugin. Any suggestion ?